# Django Cookiecutter : package folder not found

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django Project usin the cookiecutter project.
On this project I have installed [django-simple-poll](https://github.com/applecat/django-simple-poll).

All is going fine, not error message; the poll Model appears in the admin.

But, there is not folder for the 'poll' app in my project.
I presume that installing the package should create a folder for this new app with template subfolder and all the usual stuff.

Am I missing something?

Comment: May you please add to your question how exactly you installed django-simple-poll?

Comment: I ran my pipenv shell (equivalent of a virtual env) and did a simple 'pip install django-simple-poll', then added "poll" to settings.APPS. Finally ran 'python manage.py migrate'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do miss something. Only your own packages are usually located in your project folder.

When you install a package using pip the sources get downloaded into a so called environment. By default when you run pip as root it is located somewhere in your OS. The exact place differs depending on your OS and the python version used.

There is a software called [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) that allows you to create python environments on purpose (e.g. per project). I would strongly recommend using it.

You can also grab the package sources and place them directly in your project folder, if you want to. But this is not the intended way to go.

All this is possible, because python when it starts reads the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and whenever you import a package it searches in all this directories.

You can check which paths are set using [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.path)

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You can even add your own paths on runtime if necessary, but usually it is not.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I actually use pipenv.
In this case, how can I override the template of the downloaded package?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Making your own app based on the mentioned one? btw. pipenv looks very interesting! ;)

Comment: Yes indeed. The poll application has templates, and I want to override them to add style, html, etc.

Comment: Ok, [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/overriding-templates/). If you want to extend the behavior of an existing app, django provides ways for you to not change the sources directly.

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit different with the setup of django cookiecutters but this doc was helpful. Thanks